# Taking the derivative of a differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

My book jumps from

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x))g'(x) = 0 $$

to

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x, g(x)) + 2 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y} (x, g(x))g'(x) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x, g(x))(g'(x))^2 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x))g''(x) = 0.$$

It is left as an exercise to verify that this new equality can be obtained by differentiating both sides of the first equation. I've been trying to do this, but I haven't been able to get to the desired result. I'm sort of new to partial derivatives, and I would really appreciate it if someone can show me the steps that are taken when differentiating the first equation. I'm pretty sure my setup itself is wrong.

I've looked at many examples now, but I still haven't been able to get anywhere, since they are not too similar to what I have

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

---

My try:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x))g'(x)\right) $$

$$= \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,g(x)) \right)}_{\text{Term 1}} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x))g'(x)\right)}_{\text{Term 2}}$$

Now computing Term 1:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,g(x)) \right) = \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}(x, g(x)) \cdot \text{ some chain rule term} $$

What would the chain rule term be? I know in single-variable calculus, if you're doing the derivative of $f(g(x))$, then you need to multiply by $g'(x)$. But here, there are two variables.

Comment: See! Giving the attempt now allows people to tell you what you did wrong, rather than giving a correct answer which would still leave questions about your working. It was a good decision to include the working, and I have up voted in this regard.

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3074764/55235) answers your question. The notation is heavy, but it is proper.

Comment: I'm still not really getting anywhere. I think it is hard to understand because of the notation. Working backwards, I can guess that the chain rule term for Term 1 is going to be $1$. But I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: Yes, it's not easy when one's is not used to it. But it gets much easier after you get over the initial learning curve. I tried to give some guidance below.

Comment: Sorry, I had a few typos from too much copy and pasting. All good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're presumably given a function $f$ whose domain is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Since this isn't specified, I'll take the simpler approach and assume the domain is $\mathbb R^2$. This allow us to write $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Also presumably, you're given a differential function $g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

Now let's define $\varphi$ as $\varphi \colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2, x\mapsto (x, g(x))$.

You want to differentiate the function given below (with the appropriate implicit domain)

$$
x\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, g(x))g'(x)
$$

This can be rewritten as

$$
x\mapsto \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\circ\varphi\right)(x) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\circ\varphi\right)(x)\cdot g'(x)
$$

Since the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives (when they all exist), we can focus on each member of this sum separately.

We want to differentiate $\color{blue}{x\mapsto \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\circ\varphi\right)(x)}$. Now allow me to change the notation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to $\partial_1f$. They denote the same thing: the derivative with respect to the first coordinate.

In the notation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3074764/55235) answer we have $m=2$, $n=1=p$, $G=\partial_1f$, $F=\varphi$, (now because the choice of letters in both questions gets confusing, I'll use $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ (in place of $f_1$ and $f_2$ used in the linked answer), $\varphi_1\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto x$ and $\varphi_2\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto g(x)$. Now set $H=G\circ F$.

We have that $\color{blue}{H}$ is $\color{blue}{\left(\partial_1f\right)\circ \varphi}$ and this is what we wish to differentiate, in other words we wish to find $H'$. Since $H$ is a scalar function whose domain is $\mathbb R$, its components are just a singular $h_1$ in the notation of the linked answer, which yields:

$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \partial _1h_1
    \end{bmatrix}_{x}
}^{H'(x)}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_1\left(\partial_1f\right) & \partial_2\left(\partial_1f\right)
\end{bmatrix}_{\varphi(x,y)}
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\partial _1\varphi_1\\
\partial_1\varphi_2
\end{bmatrix}_{x}}^{\begin{bmatrix}
\varphi_1'\\
\varphi_2'
\end{bmatrix}_{x}}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(\partial _1\left(\partial_1f\right)\right)(x,g(x)) & \left(\partial_2\left(\partial_1f\right)\right)(x, g(x))
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
g'(x)
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(\partial _1\left(\partial_1f\right)\right)(x,g(x)) + \left(\partial_2\left(\partial_1f\right)\right)(x, g(x))\cdot g'(x)
\end{bmatrix}_.
\end{align}
$$

The last term above can be translated back to

$$
\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,g(x)) + \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(x, g(x))\cdot g'(x)
$$

It is similar for $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\circ\varphi$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The notation can be a bit confusing here. $f$ is a function of two variables. A derivative with respect to the first variable is denoted by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, a derivative with respect to the second variable is denoted by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. If instead you denote them by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$ it might be a bit clearer. At the same time you plug in the function $x$ into the first variable and the function $g(x)$ into the second variable. You are differentiating with respect to $x$ and need to apply the chain rule.

**Edit**: I will write out what happens in the first term with the renaming of variables. We want to compute: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x, g(x))\right)$$
So we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x, g(x))\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x, g(x)) \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(x) + \frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x, g(x)) \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x}g(x)$$
Simplify a bit:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x, g(x))\right)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_1}(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}(x, g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$
The second term is almost the same, you just have an extra factor of $g(x)$ that requires the product rule.

Comment: Thanks. Let me update my post with my attempt and show you where I am getting stuck

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: What *quarague* alludes to is one of the reasons why I much prefer the notation $\partial_1$, $\partial_2$, etc. Less to write, more universally applicable (as it is independent of symbols used in the definitions of the functions, as it should be), and doesn't rest on useless confusing concepts like that of "function of $x$", as if $x$ weren't a bound variable.

Comment: So here, $x_{2} = y$?

Comment: @gallileo22 Yes: $x_1$ is being used in place of $x$ and $x_2$ is being used in place of $y$.